# Is there a way to search by multiple terms using the iTunes Search API?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

i.e. searching by album and artist?

Comment: Sorry for misreading your question. It looks like the answer is "no," but I've never used the API before, so I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

No I dont think so. You can use lookup to search for multiple ids 
eg: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?amgArtistId=468749,5723